# jQuery Validator Plugin can't access dynamic field within anonymous form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've got a field in a partial that takes an email address, I want to validate this as the user types and display a message using [this plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

**Update: [Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ch341eso/2/)**

My form has no name that this field is contained within, it's actually in a partial of a partial, it's the last field I need to validate and it's giving me grief.

The main issue seems to be how I'm trying to access the field itself, as it's dynamic, using jQuery I access it through `$("input[name*='email']")` with the `rules: {}`, however I get errors when I try to use that within the validate plugin function (jquery I'm not great with, needless to say).

How can I access the email field, as it comes out something like `contacts[884414e3-9262-4a77-a448-b8f885703e9d].email`?

**jQuery:**

```
var email = $("input[name*='email']");
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            email: "required email",
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Enter your Email",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
            }
        }
    });
```

**Also tried:**

```
$('form').validate({
        rules: {
            "input[name*='email']": "required email",
        },
        messages: {
            "input[name*='email']": {
                required: "Enter your Email",
                "input[name*='email']": "Please enter a valid email address.",
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few problems with how I was trying to achieve it and some misunderstandings relating to the plugin itself.

It will work with anonymous forms and you can search for an element containing specific characters, in this case, "email".

Unsure which is the preferred implementation of the two code examples but both work. However the alternative is required for .NET it seems.

**Working Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('form').validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    $("[name*='email']").each(function() {
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: true, // will request content
            email: true // will request a valid email
        });
    });

});
```

**Working example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ch341eso/6/)**

Comment: `.messages()` is NOT a method available from this plugin.

Comment: @Sparky Just checking through the fiddles - yes you're right, will update answer, I saw that method of implementation from the documentation, didn't know it wasn't from their plugin.

Comment: Where exactly did you see `.messages()` implemented in the documentation?

Comment: Thought I did yesterday, think it was in an example but not 100% - probably my mistake.

Comment: FYI - You can put a `messages` object *inside* of the `.rules()` method.

Comment: Ah cool - through that can I get those messages to popup so they don't disturb existing content on the page? Kind of like the tooltips plugin?

Comment: jQuery Validate merely inserts an element into the DOM.  It's totally up to you to style them or integrate with a tooltip plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get at the value of the (first) email field, then use jQuery's [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

```
$("input[name*='email']").val()
```

Comment: Still has issues if I replace what I have with what you suggested.

Comment: Well I don't want the value as such I don't believe, with this method I want the field name, which I can only access through `$("input['name*='email']")`. Tried using var email  and assigning to the jQuery but that didn't work either, as it's looking for a field within the anonymous form.